# Prolog List question

Tags: apache-flex, list, prolog, frames

I am working with flex and there I have a frame called university and it has about 100 instances. I would like to store them in a list which is part of Prolog not Ksl and perform search operations. eg. the list should contain only those universities whose location is USA. thanks :)

Comment: Please provide more details. "Frame" is not a Flex Component; so I'm not sure what you mean there.  The "Frame" has 100 instances of what?  You want to store 100 instances of what as a Prolog list?  By Prolog, do you mean the early 1970's programming language? What is Ksi and how does that relate to your question?

Comment: by KSL i mean, knowledge specification language. its relevant to the field of artificial intelligence. thanks :)

Comment: Reading through the answer and other comments; I have to ask. Did you mean to tag this with Adobe Flex?  If not; what "Flex" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

To store data in Prolog, you generally add it to the fact database:

```
university(mit).
university(carnegie_mellon).
```

Then you have the freedom to either implement your predicates with Prolog's built in search, or use it to give you a list of facts with `setof/3` or `findall/3`, such as:

```
?- findall(university(X), university(X), Universities).
Universities = [university(mit), university(carnegie_mellon)].
```

You can certainly make `university` facts carry more data and use that to filter:

```
university('Oxford', uk).
university('MIT', usa).

?- findall(X, (university(X, uk)), Universities).
Universities = ['Oxford'].
```

These are very rudimentary examples. I'm afraid you are probably going to have to spend some time going through a Prolog tutorial to get further. It sounds like you will need a stronger command of this language to complete your assignment, which really is *nothing* like any other language you know.

Comment: thankyou sooo much!!!! God bless u. I simply have no clue about this language. it seems horrible to me even though i am a good programmer. I just did this in 2-3 labs that too the basics and got this assignment of making an expert system. I need to create a frame called university and supply attributes. Create 100 instances of university. Ask a couple of questions like GPA,course you want to study, country you prefer etc and render a result. please your help will mean a lot to me.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "frame." :)

Comment: :( I am using the flex environment. it maps knowledge specification language (KSL) onto equivalent prolog code. ummm, frame is analogous to a class in OOP. we define a frame called university, it has attributes like country,courses_offered,gpa_required etc. 'Oxford' will be an instance(object) of frame(class) university

Comment: I think you're just going to have to take a deep breath and start going through [Learn Prolog Now](http://www.learnprolognow.org/) or something. It will get easier, but you'll have to relax and spend some time getting into it first.

Comment: i just have to submit it day after tomorrow. :( no time to learn. could there be any other possibility? thanks for your replies dear :D

Comment: Another possibility besides learning it? No. You're on a Q&A site, not a site where people do your homework for you because you don't have time.

Comment: err.. i don't mean that. I just have to use this list feature of prolog not the whole language. the whole of my project is written in KSL. I am just in need of a similar example. :) thanks for the support.